# Copy values from CSV rows and adding to rows where the ID is the same

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv

I have a CSV of Post Codes that are linked to an ID.  There are multiple differing Postal Codes attributed to the same ID in separate rows.  My input looks like this:

```
ID      Postal Code  
1001    MK18 1TN
1001    MK18 1TL
1002    HP17 6DG
1002    HP17 6DH
```

What I want to do is to create a row for each unique ID and lists all the associated Postal Codes available for that ID.

The output I am after is similar to this:

```
ID    Postal Codes
1001  MK18 1TN, MK18 1TL
1002  HP17 6DG, HP17 6DH
```

Does anyone have any recommendations how I would achieve this in Python or SQL?

Comment: Think about the problem; it sounds like you want the `ID` column to be a key. The defaultdict container is useful here.

Comment: It is not that hard at all - but you need to show some code that you have tried.  I would encourage you to look at csv.DictReader so each row is read as a dictionary and then you can set up some new dictionaries using collections.defaultdict where the values are lists.  Having said that I am going to vote to close this question because it is not yet a programming question of the type that this site is designed to help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A python example might be:

```
#ID      Postal Code  
data = [
    ('1001', 'MK18 1TN'),
    ('1001', 'MK18 1TL'),
    ('1002', 'HP17 6DG'),
    ('1002', 'HP17 6DH'),
    ]
d = dict()
for id,pc in data:
    if id not in d:
        d[id] = []
    d[id].append(pc)
idkeys = d.keys()
idkeys.sort()
for k in idkeys:
    print k, ', '.join(d[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in Python, e.g. use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to read the input (assuming that tab is the delimter), and group it using `itertools.groupby()`, or a `collections.defaultdict(list)`. Here it is with `groupby()`.

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

with open('postcodes.csv') as infile, open('result.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(next(reader))     # copies the column headers into the output CSV
    for _id, postcodes in groupby(reader, lambda row: row[0]):
        writer.writerow([_id, ', '.join(postcode[1] for postcode in postcodes)])
```